# Why I cannot remove back button from navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have following screen:

[image]

Inspected using Debug View Hierarchy

[image]

Found that Employee List cannot be pushed to left because there is back button.

I have tried to hide the back button by

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

but doesn't work.

Anyone has idea?

Comment: You might consider trying to disable it in `prepareForSegue` on the previous VC, rather than trying to remove it once that VC is loaded.

Comment: @Rendy you have written this code [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];  in viewDidLoad() ??

Answer (score 0):

I have personally never had to do this but perhaps try using this?

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

I hope this can help.

Cheers